# How to print full request text before sending it?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm using `reqwest` to send `Post` requests to an api behind `Cloudflare`. The problem is that `Cloudflare` blocks my requests if it's not in a standard format, even if it deviates slightly from the expected request format (for example, the order of headers matter!).

I tried proxying my requests to `BurpSuite` to check the full plain text of them and everything was good and `Cloudflare` didn't block me (**Note**: `BurpSuite` is not `VPN`. It's a local proxy app that lets you view/edit your network traffic!). But without proxy, I only get back a `Cloudflare` block page. I'm guessing when request goes through proxy, the order of headers changes to the correct format!

*Now my question is*, How do I print the whole request as text before sending it, without a proxy? And how do I make sure this doesn't happen later?

```rust
// this works:
// let proxy = reqwest::Proxy::https("127.0.0.1:8080")?;
// let client = reqwest::Client::builder().proxy(proxy).build()?;

// this doesn't work!
let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;

let mut headers = reqwest::header::HeaderMap::new();

headers.insert("User-Agent", "some text".parse().unwrap());
headers.insert(reqwest::header::ACCEPT, "application/json".parse().unwrap());

let data = "{\"message\": \"Hello\", \"options\": {}}";

let request = client
    .post("https://myAPI.com/api/v1/")
    .headers(headers)
    .body(data);

let response = request.send().await?.text().await?;

println!("{}", response);
```